# Как сделать проверку доступности email через php, ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Например, уменя есть форма с полем, в это поле надо ввести email, мне надо чтоб после ввода email, без обновления странцы php скрипт проверил есть ли в бд такой email,  если есть он в форму вставил бы, например, "Такой email зарегестрирован" и заблокировалт кнопку, если в бд нету такого email то он просто очищает поле email и кнопка отправить станет доступна. 
Как это сделать на php 7, jquery, ajax?
Вот пример кода
https://pastebin.com/svVuDQiX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При каждом изменении отправляем ajax запрос:

```
$('input[name="email"]').on('change',function(){
    let email = $(this);
    let link = 'your/link'; // link to file/method which check email
    $.ajax({
      url: link,
      method: 'post',
      data: {email: email.val()},
      success: function(returnData, textStatus, jqXHR){
        let data = $.parseJSON(returnData);
        let button = email.closest('button[type="submit"]');
        if (data['success'] === true) {
          $(this).val(data[email]);
          button.attr(disabled,true);
        } else {
          $(this).val();
          button.attr(disabled,false);
        }
      }
    });
});
```

И в самом php методе/файле сперва проверяем отправлен ли пост

```
if ( isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST) ) {
```

потом выполоняем запрос типа такого, если пост отправлен, результат записываем в `$data` (опять же, нужно делать проверку - если запрос вернулся пустой то в результат пишем `'success'=>false` и можно, к примеру, убить функцию..)

```
$q = "SELECT email FROM USERS WHERE email = " . $_POST[email];
$result = ['success'=>true,'data'=>$data];
```

потом выводим результат, как-то так:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @MrDanil но, опять таки, `$q = "SELECT email FROM USERS WHERE email = " . $_POST[email];` - просто так лучше не подставлять данные в запрос, лучше сперва "обработать" `$_POST[email]` убрал спец символы и т.п..

Comment: Ну я так и сделал

Comment: Я просто не знал как отправить запрос серверу